# How to remove html code from slider?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi this is the markup I have for my image slider.

```
<div role="main">
    <div class="slideshow cycle-slideshow home-listings-slider" data-cycle-timeout="10000" data-cycle-auto-height="container" data-cycle-log="false" data-cycle-slides="div.slide" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-pause-on-hover="true">       
        <div class="cycle-prev direction"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></i></div>
        <div class="cycle-next direction"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
        <div id="pager" class="cycle-pager"></div>
        <?php 
          $images = get_option('homepage_images');  
          $image_url = get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/uploads/slideshow/'; 
          foreach($images as $image){ ?>
            <div class="slide">
            <figure>
                <a href="<?php echo $image['link']; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url . $image['large']; ?>)"></a>
                <span class="overlay-text"><?php echo $image['text']; ?></span>
            </figure>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

The part that has the navigation dots for the bottom is this, (In above code aswell)

```
<div id="pager" class="cycle-pager"></div>
```

The system automatically fills code into this on runtime but when it does we get this.

```
<span class="cycle-pager-active">•</span>
```

The dot inside the div is really killing the style, How can I remove this on the front end using PHP, JavaScript, HTML, CSS? Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Luke

Comment: Easy with this css code: `.cycle-pager-active { display: none; }`.

Comment: @Luke Simple fix. `.cycle-pager-active {overflow: hidden;}`. Bet you 1000 $.

Comment: You sir @PraveenKumar are amazing.

Comment: There is only a star. The other answers have a tick??

Comment: @Luke You are welcome! `:)`

Comment: I added to your bottom answer the tick :). Cheers!

Comment: @Luke You may wanna check out the **[tour]**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple fix.

```css
.cycle-pager-active {overflow: hidden;}
```

This works definitely.

Full code:

```css
.home-listings-slider .cycle-pager span:hover,
.home-listings-slider .cycle-pager span.cycle-pager-active {
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -99px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the contents of `.cycle-pager-active`, add this to your page, somewhere in your footer (just before closing `</body>` is fine):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout( function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.cycle-pager-active').innerHtml = "";
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

<strike>This will only run for the first DOM element in your page that has the class `cycle-pager-active`. If you have more than one and would like to empty them all, replace `.querySelector` with `.querySelectorAll`.</strike>

You don't need `jQuery` for it, but if it's already loaded in the page, you can replace the contents of the script with:

```
$(document).on('load', function(){
     $('.cycle-pager-active').html('');
})
```

This will empty all the elements with the class `cycle-pager-active`.

Comment: Thanks, ill try this now

Comment: Let me know if it's working. If it's not, it means it runs too fast and it needs to be delayed a bit. I'll adjust it if it needs to.

Comment: Nope nothing, I placed in footer line above </body>

Comment: Updated. Please try it now. If it's still not working, increase the `1000` (that is the time in miliseconds by which you are delaying the function execution)

Comment: That is quite strange. I'm afraid you need to create a [mcve] of your problem or (given the fact that you're just starting), provide a link to a live example, so we could take a look? Fixing bugs without being able to inspect them is impossible, most times.

Comment: srealestate.com.au it's the slider on home page.

Comment: Here is what is been outputted: <span class="cycle-pager-active">•</span>

Comment: Looking at your console, you are not loading `jQuery`. You need to add it in your page before you reference it. You are loading a `jQuery` plugin (namely msgbox) before loading `jQuery` itself.

Comment: Also, there is a difference between the `<script>` you added to your page and the one in my question. Please update it. I assure you it will work.

Comment: Loading `jQuery` before referencing it is really important. If you don't, scripts will create unpredictable results in your page.